# How do I find a car's vehicle type in Veins?

Tags: omnet++

In my scenario in Veins 3.0, I want to find the vType for a given car node. How do I extract this information from TraCI? 
In the `TraCICommandInterface.h` file, a function `getVehicleTypeID()` is declared but is not defined in the code. Another function `getVehicleTypeIDs()` is defined but it returns a list of the IDs only. How do I match my car with it's type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: this method is not implemented - you will need to implement it yourself. The following code might help...

```
std::string TraCICommandInterface::getVehicleTypeId(std::string nodeId) {
  return genericGetString(CMD_GET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE, nodeId, VAR_TYPE, RESPONSE_GET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, sir. I shall try it out.